# Log4j в файл и консоль в одном приложении

Tags: java, log4j

Как сконфигурировать properties так, чтобы можно было одним логгером писать в консоль, а другим в файл ?? Вот мои properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=chain\\log.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: На первый взгляд у вас всё правильно. А что не работает?

Comment: @IgorKudryashov мне нужно получить 2 логгера и чтобы 1 писал в файл, а другой в консоль

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,file` на какой-нибудь `log4j.logger.APP=DEBUG, console,file`. В коде программы инициализация логера должна производиться примерно так `logger = Logger.getLogger('APP');`

Comment: @IgorKudryashov и куда будет писать этот логгер ?

Comment: Это указывается в `log4j.logger.APP=DEBUG, console,file` в данном случае в "аппендеры" console и file

Comment: @ IgorKudryashov да мне не нужен 1 логгер который будет писать в файл и консоль. Мне нужны 2 логгера, один из которых пишет в консоль, а другой в файл

Comment: `log4j.logger.APP1=DEBUG, console` + `log4j.logger.APP2=DEBUG, file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Root logger option
log4j.logger.APP1=DEBUG, console
log4j.logger.APP2=DEBUG, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=chain\\log.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Соответственно в коде

```
loggerToConsole = Logger.getLogger('APP1');
loggerToFile = Logger.getLogger('APP2');
```

Comment: Igor Kudryashov, т.е. когда мы хотим написать уже наш лог,то должны писать так:
loggerToConsole.APP1("наш текст")???

Comment: Нет. Вы завели в программе две разные переменные-логера loggerToConsole и loggerToFile. Одна из них пишет лог в консоль, другая в файл. Соответственно, если вы хотите что-то записать в консоль, пишите `loggerToConsole.log("Ваш текст");`. В файл пишите `loggerToFile.log("Ваш текст");`